# How does TCP differentiates if the segment is lost due to corrupted segment at receiver's side or due to congestion?

Tags: tcp

I had a doubt where I am not able to find how the sender differentiates the segment loss- if it is lost since it got corrupted or it is lost due to congestion in the network?

Comment: How could the sender possibly know that? In any case, what difference woiuld it make? The sender still has to re-send it.

Answer (score 1):

TCP can differentiate the current state of the connection in question by providing different Flags in the TCP Header.

For example, the standardized handshake that is most typically seen in a TCP connection is:

**SYN,
SYN-ACK,
ACK**

Otherwise known as the *Three-Way Handshake*. Should a packet be lost during the transmission, the Sender will be able to realise its need to re-send the packet as it will NOT receive the ACK from the receiver.

Aka, the Sender will send a "SYN", and will wait for the "ACK" Flag. If one doesn't show up, no worries, the Sender will resend the SYN.

Whether that means that the packet exploded, flew off in a strange direction or got corrupted as you say, TCP doesn't care at all. TCP cares about one thing and one thing only, getting the ACK flag back from the Receiever. This is because TCP inherently trusts the lower levels of the TCP/IP network layer model to be responsible for error handling during a connection. Errors are most typically seen in layer 2 (the data link layer, which is below the transport layer that TCP works at), and there are funky algorithms at that level to manage packet errors, such as the Frame Check Sequence/Forward Error Correction (and on top of all this, IPv4, in the network layer which is again below the transport layer, has its own Header Checksum, to make sure the header doesn't get messed up either!).

Congestion however, is a different story. There are a lot of algorithms in place to ensure that congestion doesn't affect the flow of packets during a connection. The two big ones being the TCP Congestion Window and TCP Slow Start, which work in conjuction with each other. I would recommend reading up on the operation of those alogirthms, as it is too big a topic to mention in this thread, but long story short, they allow the connection to realise whether or not the flow is congested, and have appropriate responses.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control) on the subject is as good a place as any to read about it:

Hope this clears up your question!